# Splitting OpenCV operations between frontend and backend processors

Tags: opencv

- Is it possible to split an OpenCV application into a frontend and
  backend modules, such that frontend runs on thin-clients that have
  very limited processing power (running Intel Atom dual-core
  processors, with 1-2GB RAM), and backend does most the computational
  heavy-lifting s.a. using Google Compute Engine ?
- Is this possible
  with an additional constraint of the network communication between
  frontend and backend being not fast, s.a. being limited to say
  128-256kbps ?
- Are there any precedents of this kind ? Is there any such opensource
  project ?
- Are there some common architectural patters that could help
  in such design ?

***Additional clarification:***

The front-end node, need NOT be purely a front-end, as in running the user-interface. I would imagine that certain OpenCV algorithms could be run on the front-end node, that is especially useful in reducing the amount of data that needs to be sent to the back-end for processing (s.a. colour-space transformation, conversion to grayscale, histogram etc.). I've successfully tested real-time face-detection (Haar cascade) on this low-end machine, in realtime, so the frontend node can pull some workload. In fact, I'd prefer to do most of the work in the frontend, and only push those computation heavy aspects to the backend, that are clearly and definitely well beyond the computational power of the frontend computer.

What I am looking for are suggestions/ideas on nature of algorithms that are best run on Google Compute Engine, and some architectural patterns that are tried & tested, for use with OpenCV to achieve such a split.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with OpenCV. Yes you can do what you have asked, moreover you can split **any** application into frontend and backend modules. It has nothing to do with the third party libs that you are using.

Comment: Admittedly, I conveyed a slightly confusing notion of frontend & backend. Have clarified my question with additional context.

Comment: Still, this is not about OpenCV, this is a software architecture issue. You just need to know how to design your software.